# 8086 number of memory segments in the user's accessible memory

Tags: computer-architecture

I had an exam question which says how many segments the user accessible part of the 8086 memory contains?
I have count it using this:

Since from $00000$ to $0007F$ and $FFFE0$ to $FFFFF$ are made for a reserved and dedicated parts of the memmory we will take it out from the actual size of the memory which is $1MB$.

For calculating the reserved and dedicated size:
$ 0007F_{16} - 00000_{16} = 127_{10}.
$

$
FFFFF_{16} - FFFF0_{16} = 16_{10}$

$
127 + 16 = 143
$

Therefore:

$
2^{20} - 143 = 1048433_{10} 
$
$
byte \space of\space user\space accessible\space memory
$

Since each segment is a $64KB$ memory:

$
\frac{1048433 \space x\space 2^{-10}} {64} = 15.9978179932
$

So is it $15$ or $16$? Can we calculate the $0.9978179932$ as an individual segment? If we did not count it as an individual segment how does the $8086$ memmory has $16$ segments? Is the dedicated and reserverd parts are counted with the $16$ segments or what?

Comment: What *is* a *segment* in Intel 8086 context? (While *memory* has two *m*s, it does note spell with a double *m*. A spelling checker should indicate that's not the only error.)